# Binding a ListBox to an ObservableCollection of ViewModels

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

Is there a convention when using MVVM to bind the items of a ListBox to a ViewModel?

In the below XAML, I'm creating a ListBox of buttons.  The ListBox is bound to an observable collection from my ViewModel.  I then want to bind the button's Command property to an ICommand.  The problem is that when I add that binding, I'm binding against the data object, not the ViewModel.

Do I just change the MyListOfDataObjects property to be a list of ViewModels?  If so, where do I instantiate those new objects?  I'd prefer to use dependency injection since they will have several dependencies.  Do I change the GetData lambda?

In general:  what's considered good practice here?  I wasn't able to find any examples for this situation, although I assume it is rather common.

I'm using the MVVMLight framework, but I'm willing to look at any other frameworks.

```
<Window x:Class="KeyMaster.MainWindow"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                <Button Command="{Binding ButtonPressedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                        Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfDataObjects}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm using the standard MVVMLight ViewModel:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using KeyMaster.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace KeyMaster.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IDataService _dataService;
        private ObservableCollection<MyData> _myListOfDataObjects;

        public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;
            _dataService.GetData(
                (item, error) =>
                {
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    MyListOfDataObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyData>(item);
                });
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyListOfDataObjects
        {
            get { return _myListOfDataObjects; }
            set
            {
                if (_myListOfDataObjects == value) return;

                _myListOfDataObjects = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyListOfDataObjects);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I'm binding against the data object, not the ViewModel"* ?

Comment: @Blachshma I meant that the ButtonPressedCommand that is called when the button is pressed will be one that is defined in the MyData class, not the MainViewModel class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVVM, there is a clear seperation between the raw data (also known as the Model) and the ViewModel. The ViewModel is the one who is in charge of parsing the data and even modifying it to whatever form it wishes, before passing it to the View.

A simple example is having the Model as XML and having the ViewModel parse it, take only a specific property (for example a "`Name`") from each element and add them to a list. Only this list will be shown in the View.

That said, I guess you can see where I'm going - the Command should be in the ViewModel ***not*** in the Model. As you stated by yourself, you should keep as much of the UI logic out of both the VM and the Model.

If you have a specific command that does something specific on a certain type of data, you can want it in a more "general" type of ViewModel, you can use the `CanExectue` to only allow this command in specific cases. But still, the command should sit in the ViewModel.

In your specific case, I don't see a problem having the command in the ViewModel, and when raised it will do whatever you need on your data. You don't need a list of ViewModels, you need only one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it'd depend where you want the functionality of the button-press. If it is always related to the MyData object then (if possible) would it be so out of place to put the Command in the MyData object? (ps. I wouldn't call your MyData object ViewModels just because you're adding a command property to them, as they're not associated with a view)

Alternatively if you want the command in the VM then you could try bind the command using the datacontext of the window. ie something like;

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ButtonPressedCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

Although I've had trouble in the past with that and went with adding the command to the individual objects.

Comment: This binds the Command to the MainWindow class, not the MainWindowViewModel.  Changing the path to DataContext.ButtonPressedCommand} fixes that.

Comment: I've thought about this a little more and perhaps this is more of an instance of me showing my naivity in MVVM, but I thought one of the goals was to keep as much of the UI logic out of the data objects.  To that end, I have defined the data classes in a seperate project which is used by other portions of the application.  Once I add commands to this class then I'll need to add a reference to the project to WPF.  Since the data layer is also used by a web service, this seems unnatural.

Comment: @Josh Thanks for pointing out the correction. Yeh I agree with you. If it's a command that is only used in one view then it won't be good putting it in the object. I imagine if you bind to the MainWindowViewModel you'll have a method in there that contains a switch statement for all the items in your collection, which isn't wanted either. Perhaps you could create a new object specifically for that collection that inherits the MyData object - is that what you were alluding to when you mentioned a list of ViewModels?

Comment: I think your idea of a collection of objects that inherit from MyData is similar to what I was thinking in the beginning.  Again, I just assumed that there would have been an established pattern for this problem.

Comment: @Josh let me know if you find one